# pymode error detected while processing pymode#run#code_run

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, python-mode

After installed vim-plugin Pymode, at first, I can successfully run my python code in vim. But after a while, there is something wrong like this:
[image]

Comment: Please explain more about your environment

Comment: operation system is mac, and the vim is installed by brew, and the version is 8.1. the vim support python3

Answer (score 0):

This err take place when you are using default vim package. Check in terminal by :vim --version. Default vim unsupport python3 code. You have to compile vim with support python3.